# docker: "commit" requires a maximum of 2 arguments

Tags: docker

I am trying to do a docker commit from the tutorial :

```
$ docker commit -m "Added json gem" -a "majid"  9d5a8e18f150 ouruser/sinatra:v2
```

but I got :

```
docker: "commit" requires a maximum of 2 arguments.
```

I googled it, could not find a solution.
Thanks.

Comment: looks good to me. what version of docker?

Comment: Docker version 1.9.1, build a34a1d5

Comment: weird... did you try the `--author="majid" (etc)` syntax?

Answer (score 1):

the syntax for it to work is

```
docker commit -m="Added json gem" -a="majid"  9d5a8e18f150 ouruser/sinatra:v2
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, it looks like docker does not like space :

```
$ docker commit -m "addedjsongem" -a "majid"  2d9666177b46 ouruser/sinatra:v2
sha256:c43d53ba92b9099af36026d02cc85d42c3e56365a07e8e3bf3196723eca53877
```

Comment: weird, your message should be able to contain spaces... does it work with the `--message` syntax and spaces?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

I have copied instructions from web page to docker. The problem is the character `"`, because is not same.

When I typed `"` in terminal (not copied), all works fine.

I hope this solves this!